# how can I make the errors in my code appear in my terminal

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

Hello I have a problem with my code I have a code that allows to warn and watch the number of warn of a person but there is an error in my code

here it is :

```
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
slash = SlashCommand(client, sync_commands = True)
```

```
  for guild in bot.guilds:
    async with aiofiles.open(f"{guild.id}.txt", mode="a") as temp:
      pass
  client.warnings[guild.id] = {}
  for guild in client.guilds:
    async with aiofiles.open(f"{guild.id}.txt", mode="r") as file:
      lines = await file.readlines()
      for line in lines:
          data = line.split(" ")
          member_id = int(data[0])
          admin_id = int(data[0])
          reason = " ".join(data[2]).strip("\n")

          try:
            client.warnings[guild.id][member_id][0] += 1
            client.warnings[guild.id][member_id][1].append(admin_id, reason)
```

```
           @client.event
           async def on_guild_join(guild):
             client.warnings[guild.id] = {}
```

```
           @client.command()
           @commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
           async def warning(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = "Aucune raison n'a été donné"):
             await ctx.message.delete()
             try:
               first_warning = False
               client.warnings[ctx.guild.id][member.id][0] += 1
               client.warnings[ctx.guild.id][member.id][1].append((ctx.author.id, reason))

             except KeyError:
                 first_warning = True
                 client.warnings[ctx.guild.id][member.id] = [1, [(ctx.author.id, reason)]]

                 count = client.warnings[ctx.guild.id][member.id][0]
      
                 embed = discord.Embed(title = "**Nombre de warn**", description = "Un modérateur a frappé !", url = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=947274542424936508&permissions=8&scope=bot", color=0xfa8072)
                embed.set_author(name = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url, url = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=947274542424936508&permissions=8&scope=bot")
                 embed.set_thumbnail(url = "https://cdn3.emoji.gg/emojis/3968-discord-banhammer.png")
                 embed.add_field(name = "Membre", value = member.mention, inline = True)
                 embed.add_field(name = "Nombre de warn", value = count, inline = True)
                 embed.add_field(name = "Modérateur", value = ctx.author.name, inline = True)
                 embed.set_footer(text = (funFact))
                 await ctx.send(embed = embed)


           @client.command()
           @commands.has_permissions(kick_members = True)
           async def warn(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason = "Aucune raison n'a été donné"):
             embed = discord.Embed(title = "**Warn**", description = "Un modérateur a frappé !", url = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=947274542424936508&permissions=8&scope=bot", color=0xfa8072)
             embed.set_author(name = ctx.author.name, icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url, url = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=947274542424936508&permissions=8&scope=bot")
             embed.set_thumbnail(url = "https://cdn3.emoji.gg/emojis/3968-discord-banhammer.png")
             embed.add_field(name = "Membre", value = member.mention, inline = True)
             embed.add_field(name = "Raison", value = reason, inline = True)
             embed.add_field(name = "Modérateur", value = ctx.author.name, inline = True)
             embed.set_footer(text = (funFact))
             await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

I know that there is an error because it does not work but in my command terminal there is no error reported

I have tried everything but I never found a solution of letters please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would suggest learning how to use the logging module to log the operations of your script with relative details to a debugging file while it's on the server.  Then you can see what's actually happening while its running.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a simple print if your lazy like me

```py
if #do stuff
print(Error) #It doesn't really need any code it will print if it works
```

Print doesn't really need code as it'll print if the command works by itself.